# Login facebook with Laravel Socialite does not return parameters on blade

Tags: laravel, facebook, authentication, laravel-socialite

Using socialite I can return the data from the Facebook user, but I can not throw this data in my route:
Below is the code:

```php
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $user->token;
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->with(['name' => $user->name ])->redirect();
    }
```

My Services.php:

```php
  'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/painel/cadastro/facebook',
    ],
```

When i try register with facebook the erro is return:

```php
Undefined variable: name (View: C:\Autobots\Puzzle\backendmetroquadrado\resources\views\cliente\auth\facebook-register.blade.php)
```

If a dd($user) i see my facebook credencials...Someone knows how to resolve this problem? how i can put the user params in my blade. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
with()
```

should be after the redirect i think